# How to pass lists through the constructor in a thread-safe manner in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java program that reads in a large list of strings from a file, creating lists of them for every several hundred, and passes each list to a new thread that processes them in some manner.  This may include modifying the list.  I want to know the best approach to accomplishing this so that the threads don't stomp on each other's lists.  Note that I do not care about what kind of data structure this list actually is.  It could be an array, a List, a queue, stack, etc. and order does not matter.

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: If Peter Lawery is right you need not worry about synchronization if each list is thread-local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each thread has its own list, array, queue etc, there is no problem.  If you use List.subList(), you must take a copy as this creates a view into the original list (which would cause a problem if you modified it in multiple threads).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, how about `ImmutableList` (from Guava)? Each thread can subsequently copy it into its own thread-local mutable list, if it wants to.

If it really has to be mutable, a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` works too. :-)

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList takes a complete copy every time anything changes. It is best for shorter lists with a high read to write ratio. e.g. a list of observers for events.

Comment: @Peter: Of course. My point was to get as close to `ImmutableList` as possible; `CopyOnWriteArrayList` was basically just one step away from that. :-D

Comment: ImmutableList can be copied to a thread local mutable list.  You could do the same with CopyOnWriteArrayList and only copy back the changes when you have finished. (might be tricky to get right with indexes shifting around)

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with **mutable data structures** (for instance lists in which you can add / remove elements from) and you really need to **share these data structures between threads**, these would be my concerns:

- At the very least you should synchronize all access to the data structure. This is best done by wrapping the data in a class, adding some

  ```
  final Object lock = new Object();
  ```

  and do `synchronized (lock) { ... }` around all relevant operations. A loop like

  ```
  while (!isEmpty())
      remove(0);
  ```

  would be a typical example which needs to be wrapped in such `synchronized` block.
- You then need to make sure that the shared data structures is "logically synchronized" as well. If one thread for instance "adds a temporary object" which is not to be seen by the other methods, you need to lock (get exclusive right) to the data structure during this period of time. I.e. just wrapping add and remove operations in a `synchronized` block may not be enough.
- If possible, use the data structures provided in the [`java.util.concurrent package`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). These things are truly tricky, and you would save yourself one or two headaches by leveraging the already debugged data structures in this package.

  Example classes from that package include [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).

Comment: If you're really going to use locking, just use `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is you are doing partition of a large data and using each partition in a new thread.

If this is correct, I don't see a problem since a partition is not shared among threads so no chance of stomping.

For partitioning, you can simply choose a limit and create a List/array out of that data and use it.